# How can I make my site look the same on different browsers?

Tags: html, css, multiple-browsers

I'm pretty new to this stuff; all I know is enough CSS and HTML to make a site look good so if you're kind enough to answer, please be kind enough to say something I can understand :)

I've looked up "How to make a site look the same in any browser" and everyone says to check your site in different browsers every step of the way. This makes sense. But nobody can say what to do when you find a problem in anything that resembles English.

Again, I don't know much at all about this, but it seems like the same kind of problem one faces concerning whether the viewer is viewing your site on a desktop computer or a smartphone. Couldn't the solution be similar? Isn't there some kind of code I could put in that would direct different browsers to different code?

Thank you very much for looking.

P.S. I use a Mac, if that's helpful.

Comment: Being in the business for 10+ years helps much :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, like people explained browsers sometimes display sites in different ways, however most browsers nowadays render your site the same way, IE10, FF, Opera, ... Sometimes it can be hassle if your site needs to work in older browsers, like IE8, if you want this you should check if your styling rules are CSS2 or CSS3 you are using. CSS2 is widely supported while CSS3 isn't. Also there is no need to use JQuery because not only does it put strain on your website you can also achieve all the same things with vanilla Javascript, but since you're talking about CSS I don't think that is relevant for the moment. However you will be forced to make two different layouts for your site for mobiles and tablets if you want your site to be user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries (like jQuery for JavaScript) that will help you to automatically deal with many browser specific issues. Furthermore, you should use HTML and CSS validators to make sure that you use valid X(HTML) and CSS. However, in the end you will still have to check your site in different browsers. You can use a service like browsershots.org for it.

Comment: Thank you both very much for answering, but I don't think you get my question.  I know to check my site in different browsers, my question is: When my neatly arranged colored text boxes, which are beautiful in my Safari and Firefox browsers, overlap and run into each other on a Windows, how do I fix it?  Obviously if I change the spacing to accommodate the one, it will have the opposite effect on the other, what do I do?  How do I make the browser understand that "This code will work for you, not this one"?